# Saving Map Marker Reference

Tags: android, google-maps

I was wondering if someone could help me, I am trying to save a reference to a newly created Marker in a ConcurrentHashMap, I seem to have no problem storing the reference but when I try to retrieve it the app crashes and throws a NullPointer Exception, below is how I store and retrieve my marker.

Storing it in `mMarkers` which is `private Map<LatLng, Marker> mMarkers = new ConcurrentHashMap<LatLng, Marker>();`

```
LatLng currPos = new LatLng(map.getCameraPosition().target.latitude,map.getCameraPosition().target.longitude);
        Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(currPos)
        );
        mMarkers.put(currPos, marker);
         locationCount++;


     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();           


     editor.putString("mlat"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), Double.toString(marker.getPosition().latitude));


     editor.putString("mlng"+ Integer.toString((locationCount-1)), Double.toString(marker.getPosition().longitude));

     editor.putInt("locationCount", locationCount);               

     editor.putString("mzoom", Float.toString(map.getCameraPosition().zoom)); 

     editor.commit();
```

Removing it where it fails

```
map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

            Marker marker = mMarkers.get(point);

            marker.remove(); //fails here
            mMarkers.remove(point);             
        }
    });
```

I am using the markers LatLng position as the key to store it.

```
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at com.grim.pipboid.FragmentMap$1.onMapLongClick(FragmentMap.java:154)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$7.onMapLongClick(Unknown Source)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.j$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:310)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at euq.a(SourceFile:93)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at maps.c.j.b(Unknown Source)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at maps.ay.an.c(Unknown Source)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at maps.ay.bc.onLongPress(Unknown Source)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at maps.bo.g.onLongPress(Unknown Source)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at maps.bo.h.c(Unknown Source)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at maps.bo.i.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
04-06 16:52:05.535: E/AndroidRuntime(26601):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user can long-click anywhere on the map. It does not have to be at the precise latitude and longitude of an existing marker. Hence, your `LatLng` does not exist in the `HashMap`.

Comment: But in this case the user isn't as I'm just testing and I am pressing on the marker. Would you be able to suggest a better way then?

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you were getting at, I've added it to the OnMarkerClick Listener now thank you.